# R apply function to rows of data frame using values as arguments

Tags: r, apply

I have a df `TRX` with pairs of Date and Curreny

```
Date            Currency      ExchangeRate
2012-08-13      EUR           ?
2012-08-13      CHF           ?
2012-08-13      CZK           ?
```

I have a second df CURRENCIES for the currency conversion rates with EUR base.

```
Date            EUR    CHF       CZK
2012-08-13      1      1.24      25.73
2012-08-13      1      1.23      25.92
2012-08-13      1      1.22      24.00
```

Now I want to translate the day rates. I wrote a function for this liske
getDayRate(date,currency).

```
getDayRate <- function(date, currency) {
currencies[which(as.character(currencies[,c("Date")]) == date),c(currency)]
}

getDayRate("2013-06-20","EUR")
```

Now I want to apply `getDayRate(date,currency)` to each row of `TRX` so that for each row it uses the first and second element as arguments so I get teh `ExchangeRate`.

`apply(x,1,fun())` does not work as it requires a matrix with numbers. In theory i would have to convert the dataframes to the indices and then use apply.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you post the `getDayRate` function ?

Comment: Take a look at `mapply`.

Comment: +1 I think `mapply` is the way to go

Comment: can you post an mapply example?

Comment: I think there is at least one typo in your function... `c(currency)` you should use the parameter `currency` to filter and not to programmatically select a column

Comment: ok now it makes sense...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `mapply` you could do something like:

```
mapply(getDayRate, TRX$Date, TRX$Currency)
```

Comment: where is the dataframe I am applying to?

Comment: You said your dataframe was called `currencies`. So, this uses the two vectors `Date` and `Currency` from that. Syntax for `mapply` is a bit different than `apply` (specifically, function comes before data, data before function).

Comment: I get this error: Error in mapply(getDayRate, currencies$Date, currencies$Currency) : 
  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length

Comment: I can't reproduce that error with the data you've provided. You should include a `dput(head(df))` for both of your dataframes in your original question.

Comment: it works like this: mapply(getDayRate, as.character(trx$Date), trx$Currency). However, this is really slow. My df trx has 6 million rows. Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: I think Michele's suggestion to step back from the current coding problem and provide a bit more detail in the question on your broader objectives will lead to an efficient solution. My answer solves the problem as you've described it, but I suspect it's not the most direct route from your data to your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

The output you want is not so clear. your function `getDayRate` retrieves directly, from the `currencies` table hard-coded into it, the ExchangeRate chosen date and currency which makes sense so far.

However, running your function against the same table it retrieves the values from we give the same result of just selecting that column...

```
> all.equal(mapply(getDayRate, currencies$Date, currencies$Currency), currencies$ExchangeRate, check.attributes=F)
[1] TRUE
```

Probably (I think) you actually want to do some joins (with the second table you provided?) linking another table to the `currencies` data.frame by `date` and `currency`.

EDIT:

your edit now clarifies things. why don't you try also this

```
library(reshape2)

melt(currencies)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it to get `apply` to work:

```
apply(your_df, 1, function(x) {getDayRate(x[1], x[2])})
```

Comment: that should work, but I get a an error: Error in as.matrix.data.frame(X) : 
  dims [product 5000] do not match the length of object [5009]

Comment: problem is it seems apply converts the dataframe to a matrix. in that conversion the  matrix is longer than my data frame and I have no idea why

Comment: try with `adply` from `plyr`. the actual problem is the everything in this question seems meaningless to me...

Comment: @user670186 I'm guessing that's because your function doesn't return a single number; I agree with Michele, it's unclear what you're trying to do - what exactly is `ExchangeRate` supposed to be? why do you have several dates per currency in your `currencies` table?